# linux: how to redirect the running command in one line bsub in LSF job system?

Tags: linux, redirect, lsf

I am submitting jobs on cluster equiped with LSF job system.

I don't like to write job script. I prefer one line `bsub`, such as

```
bsub -n 24 mpirun -n 24 ./a.out
```

It is running fine. But I want real time screen output.

So I tried

```
bsub -n 24 mpirun -n 24 ./a.out >stdout
```

But this won't work, because it just redirect the information of job submitting not the output of running command

Though I know bsub provide `-o` and `-e` to redirect output. But these two command is not real time. As I tested, they save the whole screen output after the job completed. But this is not what I want. What is more, I also know `bpeek`, and this is not I want either.

**So my question is how to correctly redirect the output of running command inside one line `bsub`?**  I tried several way, make the command quoted, bracketed... all failed

Comment: IMO, redirecting the output in your job script is the right way to do it. But thinking of other options:  LSF will direct the stdout and stderr of the job to a file in the LSF_TMPDIR (which is $HOME/.lsbatch by default).  You could tail that file.  e.g., If your jobid is 100, and your cluster uses the default value of LSF_TMPDIR, you could try this: `tail -f $HOME/.lsbatch/*.100.out`

Answer (score 0):

```
bsub -I -n 24 mpirun -n 24 a.out
```

The `-I` tells LSF to run the job interactively, ie to send the output to your console.

This only works if there's a default interactive queue defined.

Comment: Hi, Squirrel. Thank you for answering. But I don't want the output to console, I want it to save to a file. And -I is not stable for long time jobs